# Unchangeable Python Class Instance Attribute

Tags: python

So I've been reading up on descriptors to try and get a better grasp of how they work and while I know you cannot really prohibit things in Python, the lightbulb lit up and this idea came to me (I remembered reading about instance bound descriptors [here](https://dev.to/mattconway1984/python-creating-instance-properties-2ej0) and borrowed the implementation):

```
class Immutable:
    __slots__ = "name"

    def __init__(self, name):
        def name_setter(obj, val):
            print("Cannot change name!")
        self.name = property(lambda obj: name, name_setter)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        try:
            # Try invoking the descriptor protocol __set__ "manually"
            got_attr = super().__getattribute__(attr)
            got_attr.__set__(self, value)
        except AttributeError:
            # Attribute is not a descriptor, just set it:
            super().__setattr__(attr, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        # If the attribute does not exist, super().__getattribute__()
        # will raise an AttributeError
        got_attr = super().__getattribute__(attr)
        try:
            # Try "manually" invoking the descriptor protocol __get__()
            return got_attr.__get__(self, type(self))
        except AttributeError:
            # Attribute is not a descriptor, just return it:
            return got_attr


mark = Immutable("Mark White")
print(mark.name)

mark.name = "test1"
print(mark.name)

setattr(mark, "name", "test2")
print(mark.name)

mark.__setattr__("name", "test3")
print(mark.name)

jon = Immutable("Jon Snow")
print(jon.name)
print(mark.name)
```

Output:

```
Mark White
Cannot change name!
Mark White
Cannot change name!
Mark White
Cannot change name!
Mark White
Jon Snow
Mark White
```

The idea is that this restricts the name attribute from getting changed because it is created as a property whose setter is that function defined in __init__. Also, the custom __setattr__ and __getattribute__ functions allow the descriptor to be instance bound. So the value is set when the object is created and that's it. Even the **__dict__** cannot be altered due to **__slots__** being defined.

So my question is:

Am I not seeing something extremely obvious or is this attribute really not changeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this attribute is definitely changeable:

```
object.__setattr__(mark, 'name', 'Foo')
```

Will successfully set the name.

Not sure what the point of "instance bound" descriptors is. This would never pass any sane code review.

Comment: Ah, and there it is. Makes sense that a parent's class __setattr__ would work. Not really sure about the instance bound descriptors either. I just remembered stumbling upon that article a while back and looked it up again.